# Separate SSD partition for OS and software?

Tags: partitioning, ssd

I'm getting a new laptop with **two SSD**'s:

- 500 GB for OS (Win10) and software (games, antivirus, image/video editing software)
- 1TB for (lots) of personal data, like music, pics, videos

Should I make two partitions on the 500GB SSD, one just for the OS, and the other for the rest of the software ? Or should I just install everything in one partition ?

Comment: A user would be hard-pressed to exceed the need for a Windows partition over 300GB (307,200MB), provided they move the user data directories to a separate partition, a practice all should adhere to since it makes restoring Windows far easier and more convenient on an end user.  To do so, right-click on each user data directory (`%UserProfile%\Documents`, `%UserProfile%\Downloads`, etc) > _Properties_.  Select the _Location_ tab, fill in the new path for the directory (i.e. `D:\<username>\Documents`), then click _Move_

Comment: As to the partition structure of the 500GB SSD, it will have a minimum of 4 partitions for UEFI (WinRE, ESP, MSR, OS).  Keep in mind the last partition on any SSD should have 10% of the SSD's total size reserved for O[ver]P[rovisioning] (~47GB, _i.e. 47GB [on a 500GB drive] + the size you want for data_).

Comment: As @JW0914 suggests, you can also move other data folders, such *My Pictures* and *My Videos* easily. Keep *Program Files* and *Program Files (x86)* and Windows system files on the C: drive.

Answer (score 1):

Established programming practices of Windows app publishers could make dividing the OS and Program Files between drive letters (and their partitions) a moot point, if not counter productive. I've seen many apps not work reliably if installed to a drive other than %SYSTEMDRIVE% .

Instead, put not only Users and their data on the second physical drive, but other Windows files as well. The swap file, page file, %TEMP% and %TMP%, all can live on that second drive, which distributes drive processing load across the drives for a (minor) performance boost. However, if you use hibernation, don't try to move the hibernation file out of %SYSTEMDRIVE% .

Comment: I totally agree with @K7AAY.  Splitting the partition will just (possibly) make a pain in the butt for you later on.  One other thing.. you can move folders from drive to drive and [junction](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/hard-links-and-junctions) them back to the original location